# WebStorm expecting multiple arguments for $.insertBefore()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm

I have the following code which is currently working as desired.  It inserts elements into `objGrid` according to the property `loadOrder`.

```
let $elTileTitle = $('<div/>', { class: 'tileTitle', html: tile.title });

let $elNext;
for (let i = tile.loadOrder; i < objectLength(tiles); i++) {
    let $potentialNext = $(`.tile[data-loadorder="${i}"]`);
    if ($potentialNext.length > 0) {
        $elNext = $potentialNext;
        break;
    }
}
if (typeof $elNext !== 'undefined') {
    $elTile.insertBefore($elNext);
} else {
    let $elPrev;
    for (let i = tile.loadOrder; i < 0; i--) {
        let $potentialPrev = $(`.tile[data-loadorder="${i}"]`);
        if ($potentialPrev.length > 0) {
            $elPrev = $potentialPrev;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (typeof $elPrev !== 'undefined') {
        $elTile.insertAfter($elPrev);
    } else {
        $elTile.appendTo(objGrid);
    }
}
```

As stated, this seems to work well.  But I noticed a warning in my IDE that `insertBefore()` had an invalid number of arguments.  After viewing the documentation, I replaced that line with this:

```
$('#grid').insertBefore($elTile,$elNext);
```

This has presented odd behavior.  After this code runs, `$('#grid')` is empty.  Oddly, all the tiles exist in the DOM (ie, if I type `$('#tile-store')` in the console, I get an object back with all the expected properties), however I cannot find them in the HTML ("Elements" tab) and the UI is blank.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I can provide more information if needed

Comment: Other questions I've seen about IDE bugs haven't been considered off-topic, FWIW; others may have the same question when WebStorm does this to them. :-) I see you've added the [tag:webstorm] tag, which is a good idea. Perhaps change the title to "Why does WebStorm tell me insertBefore has invalid arguments?" or some such to aid searchability...

Comment: Good tip. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I noticed a warning in my IDE that insertBefore() had an invalid number of arguments.

Your IDE is mistaken. It's mistakenly applying the rules for [the DOM's `insertBefore`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-952280727) to your use of **jQuery's** [`insertBefore`](http://$elTile.insertBefore($elNext);). Your original use of jQuery's is just fine. **If** you were using the DOM's, you'd need to give it another argument. But they're completely different functions.

Comment: Sigh. Now that you post this I remember that I already discovered this and even asked about it. It was filed as a bug for JetBrains.

Comment: I couldn't find the bug, so I opened https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30081